# Passing methods through child components using React-Hook-Forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, react-hook-form

I am trying to use the `register()` method in my child component. But I am getting a Typescript Error saying: `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.`

I am assuming I am passing the register method incorrectly?

**Parent Component**

```
type FormValues = {
  projectType: string;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const {
    register,
  } = useForm<FormValues>({ mode: 'all' });
  return (
    <Container>
      <FormBlock id="form">
        <fieldset>
          <ChildComponent props={register()}/>
        </fieldset>
      </FormBlock>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
const ChildComponent = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <InputField {...props.register('projectType')}></InputField
  );
};
```

Comment: In the parent component, your code is trying to call the register function and pass the return value as props rather than passing the function itself as a prop.

Comment: What is the best way to pass it though correctly? Using ```this.register```?

Comment: By calling `register` you are not passing the function to `ChildComponent` but the return value. Also you wouldn't pass a prop `props` to a component. The arguments provided to `ChildComponent` are already the props and wrapped into an object. Just pass `register={register}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've to update the following line to:

```
<ChildComponent props={register} />
```

You shouldn't call `register`, you've to remove the parenthesis

**EDIT:** thanks to Calvin

You've to edit the component:

```
<InputField {...props('projectType')}></InputField>
```

It's cleaner to rename `props` to `register`

```
<ChildComponent register={register} />

// Field
<InputField {...register('projectType')}></InputField>
```

Comment: I changed ```register()``` to ```register```. But I am having an error with the props argument in the child component. Tried doing ```(props)``` or ```({props})``` but Im getting: ```Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.```. Is this an issue due to me passing through a method ?

Comment: You should probably pass it as `<ChildComponent props={{register}} />` so that `<ChildComponent>` gets passed a prop called `register`. In `<ChildComponent>`, you should add the type of the `<ChildComponent>`'s prop object (an object with a property called register).

Comment: Also, when doing curly braces in a function's argument list like that, you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) the function's first argument and retrieving a property called `props` from it. So to get just `register` from the passed in props, you would do `({register}: ChildComponentProps)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass props form properties to nested components with `useForm`, `useFormContext` and `FormProvider`.

You need to get form methods with `useForm()` in the parent component, wrap its content with `<FormProvider>` and fetch form methods from child components using `useFormContext()`.

Code from official docs:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <NestedInput />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

function NestedInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input {...register("test")} />;
}
```

Link: https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/